# JQuery slider function not working

Tags: jquery

Im new to JQuery and having some problems. I would like to make my sub navigation bar slide open after clicking on the main navigation on what i would like to see. But i cant seem to get it working.

Could someone help please?

Code below:

HTML

```
<div id="navigation_bar">
    <ul>                        
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>                        
        <li><a href="">Beauty Treatments</a></li>                                                
        <li><a href="">Holistic Treatments</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Pamper Parties</a></li>
        <li><a href="">After care</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Testermonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Special offers</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="sub_navigation">

</div>
```

CSS

```
#navigation_bar ul {
    line-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigation_bar li {
    float:left;
    margin-left:0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigation_bar li a:link, #navigation_bar li a:visited {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display:block;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    margin:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#222;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    line-height:36px;
    border:none;
}

#navigation_bar li a:hover, #navigation_bar li a:active {
    border:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-image:url(Images/mouse_over_background.gif);
}

#navigation_bar li a.current {
    background-image:url(Images/mouse_over_background.gif); 
    border:none;
    color:#0065b0;
}

#navigation_bar li a.current:hover {
    cursor:default;
    color:#0065b0;
}

#sub_navigation{
    background-image:url(Images/subnav_background.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-15px;
    width:1140px;
    height:50px;
    z-index:1;
}

#subnav_text {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:25px;
    float:left;
    padding-left:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

JQuery

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navigation_bar li").click(function(){
        $("#sub_navigation").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

Within the head of the document i reference the latest JQuery libary

Comment: What does "not working" mean? If it's not sliding down are you hiding the element first? Works fine in a fiddle if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#sub_navigation {
    display: none; //The slideDown effect depends on the element being hidden.
}
```

And change this in your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#navigation_bar li a").on('click', function(e){
        //We don't want the links to go elsewhere. 
        //Without this we wouldn't see the slide.
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("#sub_navigation").slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/vm6NB/

**UPDATE:**

```
#sub_navigation {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
}
```

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vm6NB/4/

Comment: Ah the sub navigation as you can see from the CSS has a background colour and that is what i want to hide also. Should this script do this? as its still not at the moment.

Comment: It hides the entire element. So if it has a background, that will be invisible as well. I've updated the Fiddle so you can see this working clearly.

Comment: Now the sub nav flashes then disappears again. I can see it working on the fiddle but not on the web. Maybe it just needs to be slowed down even further from the option slow. It just seems to pop up instead of slide. From the fiddle also the main navi slides up, but im after the sub navi to slide down

Comment: Give me the link to your web page that you're testing on.

Comment: By changing your `#sub_navigation`'s position to `absolute` and setting  `top: 120px` we get this: http://jsfiddle.net/vm6NB/4/
Is that what you want?

Comment: www.emmanolanbeautytherapy.co.uk, Its by no mean finished but the home and beauty tab has some basic pages to it. Yes that is exactly what im after. Ill update that now

Comment: Ive updated it. But it still just flicks on unlike the fiddle script which is perfect. Ive put all the JQuery on the page instead of being in a seperate file.

Comment: You have two problems in your page. 1: Put your JS in the bottom of the page just before the `</body>` instead of the top. 2: Your code ins't the one I put in my answer.

Comment: Sorry it works now. Why does the script need to be at the bottom? Can i reference if from another file?

Comment: We put the script on the bottom so to insure everything has been loaded. And yes you can reference from another .js file. Remember to accept an answer and up-vote when you get the chance.

Comment: Does that reference need to be put at the bottom also?

Comment: You should always reference your jQuery and any Javascript files at the bottom whenever possible. Some libraries you have to put them on top (ex. Modernizr).

Answer (score 0):

Try it with these tweaks (start with it up, stop the anchor tags from firing).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sub_navigation").slideUp();
    $("#navigation_bar li").click(function (event) {

        $("#sub_navigation").slideDown("slow");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah the sub navigation as you can see from the CSS has a background colour and that is what i want to hide also. Should this script do this? as its still not at the moment.